# content_tag conditional HTML attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a relatively simple question. I have a line of code like this:

```
content_tag(:span, some_variable, { :class => span_class })
```

but if the variable `span_class` is nil, this outputs `<span class>some_variable</span>`.

I want the hash to only occur under some condition. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
content_tag(:span, some_variable, { :class => span_class } if some_condition)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting `<span class>` in the HTML? That looks more like your DOM inspector's way to representing `<span class="">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised that it's doing what you say, I would expect:

```
content_tag :span, some_variable, :class => span_class
```

to not return a class if `span_class` is nil. However, I think you could get back to valid markup by just passing `||''`, like so:

```
content_tag( :span, some_variable, :class => span_class||'' )
```